# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException Permission denied to access property 'H'

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Please can someone suggest on this exception?

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException Permission denied to access property 'H'

Comment: I suggest you to provide more information, e.g. source code of your test, page you are testing, to start with.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078721/permission-denied-to-access-property-h