# Permission denied to access property "H"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have written the below code to capture the entire screen shot of a webpage using java script.

**I'm Using:**
**Firefox Version:** 49.0.1
**Chrome Version:** 54.0.2840.59 m
**Selenium Version:** 3.0.0
**OS:** Win10 64 bit
**Java:** 1.8

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class ScreenCapture {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
        File capture = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(capture, new File("C:\\Users\\Vishvambruth JT\\Desktop\\FlipKart.jpg"));
    }
}
```

The webpage will scroll down but the code stops abruptly with the below error. Could you please help.

```
1476679740598   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:38310
Oct 16, 2016 11:49:00 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
1476679741083   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\VISHVA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.h4P3qq7Ekmrz
1476679741083   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
1476679741083   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:50064
1476679742059   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 50064
1476679743366   Marionette  INFO    startBrowser 6f833edf-0ff4-4f1f-869c-1de62f8626a9
Oct 16, 2016 11:49:03 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Permission denied to access property "H"
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '350cf60', time: '2016-10-13 10:43:56 -0700'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-JUUNTJIC', ip: '10.0.0.112', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, marionette=true, firefoxOptions={args=[], prefs={}}, appBuildId=20160922113459, version=, platform=XP, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=9960, browserVersion=49.0.1, platformVersion=10.0, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=windows_nt, device=desktop}]
Session ID: 6f833edf-0ff4-4f1f-869c-1de62f8626a9
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:537)
    at ScreenCapture.main(ScreenCapture.java:19)
```

Comment: use wires.exe instead of geckodriver.exe and in your local system name it as wires instead of geckodriver

Comment: @PotnuruRavi, you want me to rename the geckodriver.exe file to wires.exe and change the code as below: System.setProperty("webdriver.wires.driver","C:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\wires.exe");

Comment: exactly but don't save the file as wires.exe. You can save it as wires

Comment: @PotnuruRavi What do you mean by saying "don't save the file [...] You can save it" ??? It doesn't make sens!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for Selenium Web Driver 3.0.1.
The problem was gone when switching to version 2.53.1.

Answer (score 0):

I too got this issue and after some research, I can say it is not problem of Selenium. It is problem with gecko driver. You can run it with chrome and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just update to Firefox Night and it will work.

The Firefox Night can be found at https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/ (the one labeled Beta).

It's better to use an up-to-date webdriver version with an up-to-date Firefox Night version (all the code and efforts of development and code issues are focused on that synchronization, and of course it makes sense in order to cover newer final users scenarios better).